# if the user provides same input more than X amount of time print something

Tags: python

I'm doing some while loop exercises and got stuck with one question.

```
n = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :)\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
while n == "right" or n == "Right":
    n = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n******       ***\n  (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
print("\nYou got out of the Lost Forest!\n\o/")
```

The assignment is to expand this code to show a sad face if you go right
twice and flip the table any more times than that.
Hint: use a counter.

Comment: please post properly indented code

Comment: Tip: Use a counter

Comment: What more do you think we can say than the hint in the exercise?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
counter = 0
while {bool based on n}:  # Check if n is the string you're looking for
    ...
    counter += 1  # Increment counter (because n matched)
    if counter == 2:  # n matched twice
        print(":(")
    if counter > 2:  # n matched more than two times
        # table flip
        ...
    ...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.